# C++ Calling a copy constructor on an unknown derived class through an abstract base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor, abstract-base-class

I'm making a tree that has several different node types: a binary node, a unary node, and a terminal node. I've got an ABC that all the nodes inherit from. I'm trying to write a recursive copy constructor for the tree like so:

```
class gpnode
{
public:
  gpnode() {};
  virtual ~gpnode() {};
  gpnode(const gpnode& src) {};

  gpnode* parent;
}

class bnode:gpnode
{
public:
  bnode() {//stuff};
  ~bnode() {//recursive delete};

  bnode(const bnode& src)
  {
    lnode = gpnode(src.lnode);
    rnode = gpnode(src.rnode);

    lnode->parent = this;
    rnode->parent = this;
  }

  gpnode* lnode;
  gpnode* rnode;
}

class unode:gpnode
{
public:
  unode() {//stuff};
  ~unode() {//recursive delete};

  unode(const unode& src)
  {
    node = gpnode(src.node);

    node->parent = this;
  }

  gpnode* node;
}
```

My problem is that I can't do

```
node = gpnode(src.node);
```

because gpnode is a virtual class. I could do

```
node = unode(src.node);
```

but that doesn't work when the child of a unode is a bnode. How do I get it to intelligently call the copy constructor I need it to?

Comment: `src.node` is a pointer. The constructor you have have the reference as argument. I think it should be `unode(*(src.node))`

Comment: True. In my actual code, I believe it's correct, but here I just forgot that detail when writing the example.

Comment: LinuxMercedes  

_>because gpnode is a virtual class_

what do u mean by virtual class here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to implement cloning.

```
   class base
   {
   public:
       virtual base* clone() const = 0;
   }

   class derived : public base
   {
   public:
       derived(){}; // default ctor
       derived(const derived&){}; // copy ctor

       virtual derived* clone() const { return new derived(*this); };
   };
```

Etceteras

Comment: +1 for getting the `clone` function right (too many people forget either the `const` qualifier or the covariance of the return type).

Comment: I guess it's possible to automate _clone_ implementation with curiously recurring  pattern

Comment: Regardless of this being an old question, you got me curious. Why is const needed with clone exactly?

Comment: @Yannick, same reason we use the `const` qualifier on any member function - we're not *modifying* anything, and a clone should not modify anything. :)

Comment: Tahns a lot for the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

To do this you have to provide a `clone`-method for your objects, that returns a pointer of the appropriate type. If all your classes have copy-constructors, that is as simple as that:

```
node* clone() const {
    return new node(*this);
}
```

Where `node` is the class you are writing the `clone`-method for. You would of course have to declare that method in your base-class:

```
virtual gpnode* clone() const = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [virtual constructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8).

Comment: Pure link are generally frown upon, your answer would be better were you to cite an excerpt or present the link in some way in order to get people excited about visiting the link.