# What's the point of virtual copy constructors (clone functions)?

Tags: c++

With virtual copy constructors, a class `Vehicle` has a `copy()` virtual member function that all inherited classes like `Car` will implement.

Later some other class can have any type of vehicle as a member variable:

```
struct Foo {
  Vehicle *v;
  Foo(const Vehicle &veh) {
    v = veh.clone();
  }
};
```

I don't see the point. Why not get rid of `clone()` and do `new` "in place" like this

```
struct Foo {
  Vehicle *v;
  Foo(Vehicle *veh) {
    v = veh; //veh has no clone()
  }
  ~Foo() {
    delete v;
  }
};

//elsewhere
Foo f(new Car());
```

What are the drawbacks (other than it only working for "in place" creation)? Now nobody has to implement clone and everything seems much easier.

Comment: Copying a pointer isn't the same as copying the pointee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your example, it works fine. But what if:

```
 Foo* MakeCar()
 {
    Car c;
    Foo *f = new Foo(&c); 
 }
```

or:

```
 Car *c = new Car;
 Foo f(c);
 delete c;
 ... use f in a way that needs c here.
```

By cloning the object, you don't have the problems that I've just created above. The Foo object is fully in control of the lifetime of the Car.

Edit: and it has to be a virtual function, so that `Car` and `MotorBike` and `Truck` can do different things depending on what object it actually is.

Comment: Can the clone function be avoided if we know that: A) The objects are "immutable", i.e. cannot be changed by anyone after they are created. B) We use smart pointers (shared_ptr) to the objects? Is that a good idea?

Comment: Immutability won't help in either of the cases I showed above. I think a smart pointer can't point at a local object, and it tracks the lifetime of the object, so that will probably work. As far as I'm aware, smart pointers are always a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

The point of them is when you have an *existing* pointer to a base class and want a copy of "whatever it is".

Consider:

```
class Base;
class Derived1 : public Base;
class Derived2 : public Base;

Derived1* d1 = new Derived1();
Derived2* d2 = new Derived2();
makeACopy(d1);
makeACopy(d2);

void makeACopy(Base* base) {
    // ???  What is it?
};
```

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122789/copy-object-keep-polymorphism/4122835#4122835) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912994/c-calling-a-copy-constructor-on-an-unknown-derived-class-through-an-abstract-b/7913060#7913060).

Comment: I don't get this. What's makeACopy doing?

Comment: @7Cows, it was supposed to be illustrative ;) Check out the other answers.  Cloning is used when we have a pointer to the base-class and want a copy of the concrete class *whatever it may be*.

Answer (score 1):

Because your second example doesn't follow the rule of three, and will therefore crash if Foo is ever copied (for instance if you ever used Foo in a std::vector).

Most of the time in C++ you need working copy constructors, and clone is a good way to have that.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this:

```
Car *c = new Car();
Foo f1(c);
Foo f2(c);
```

...then watch the fireworks when the Foo destructors are called.