# Creating a new pointer to a pure virtual class

Tags: c++, abstract-base-class

I have a class of the following design:

```
class Meal {
public:
    virtual void cook() = 0; // pure virtual
}

class Omelette : Meal {
public:
    void cook() {/*do something*/}; // non-virtual
}

class Waffle : Meal {
public:
    void cook() {/*do something*/}; // non-virtual
}

std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Meal> > menu;

void addMeal(const Meal& meal) {
    menu.emplace_back(new Meal(meal)); // cannot allocate an object of abstract type
}
```

I'm unable to find a way of adding a `Meal`-derived object to the `menu` since I cannot create an abstract object. Is there a way of performing the above code?
I'd prefer that `Meal` remain abstract. I could pass in a pointer to an existing `Meal`-derived object, but then my unique_ptr is hardly unique.

Comment: Pass in a `unique_ptr<Meal>`; `emplace_back` will move it into the vector. This is how you document transfer of ownership. Or, use `shared_ptr` for shared ownership - whichever best suits the rest of your design.

Comment: Add a virtual function called `clone` and make each derived class implement that. Use that function in your `addMeal` function.

Comment: Delegating non-expiring pointer creation to the code that knows which object they operate with should work, as @IgorTandetnik says

Comment: This is where [factory pattern](http://www.sourcetricks.com/2008/05/c-factory-pattern.html) comes in handy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this problem is the [virtual copy constructor](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advanced-c-virtual-copy-constructor/); which is not allowed in C++ (It is not allowed because constructor is something related to the class itself, it can't be delegated to class's children). That why `clone` is the best fit for this problem.

Here is a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913060/231388), with most popular syntax.

So, you code shall be

```
class Meal {
public:
    virtual void cook() = 0; // pure virtual
    virtual Meal* clone() const = 0; // pure virtual clone.
};

class Omelette : public Meal {
public:
    void cook() {
    /*do something*/ 
    }; // non-virtual
    virtual Omelette* clone() const
    {
        return new Omelette(*this);
    }
};

class Waffle : public Meal {
public:
    void cook() {
        /*do something*/
    }; // non-virtual
    virtual Waffle* clone() const
    {
        return new Waffle(*this);
    }
};

std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Meal> > menu;

void addMeal(const Meal& meal) {
    menu.emplace_back( meal.clone() ); // cannot allocate an object of abstract type
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a `getNew` virtual method which returns a new copy of the (derived) object and use that instead.